# annotation based DI with Producers

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Are there any DI frameworks in the .Net world that is simple and which does not require too much meta-data configuration for eg. using xml etc?

A very good example from the Java world would be JBoss Weld.  With Weld it is possible to have producer methods (methods that can be marked with custom annotation) that return objects.  The objects produced above can be injected where needed.  This saves a lot of meta-data configuration.  Ofcourse Weld needs an xml too, but it does not mandate extensive configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) lets you bind your types like this in code:

```
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Ninja>();
```

for contextual binding with ninject that uses attributes have a look at [this](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

Create an attribute to decorate your class with

```
class ClimberNeeded : Attribute{}
```

Bind the interface to the implementation with a given context `WhenClassHas`

```
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().WhenClassHas<ClimberNeeded>();
```

Decorate your class with the attribute.

```
[ClimberNeeded]
class MountainousAttack {
    [Inject]
    IWarrior StandardMountainWarrior { get; set; }
}
```

here `StandardMountainWarrior` will be a `Samurai` instead of a `Ninja`.

---

Then there's [TinyIOC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC) which is even better it has autoregister :) or you can do:

```
container.Register<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>();
```

---

And [funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/) which lets you write clever delegates to resolve your types. which is really lacking documentation. But there's a nice [vidcast](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/02/02/116399.aspx).

---

and lots more of course. for example [unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/), [structuremap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) and [windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) which all have "in code" configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for [NInject](http://www.ninject.org/) too. But almost any other IoC container for .NET now is code configurable. I did suggest to avoid using annotations, but prefer constructor injection instead. Annotation, or better attributes since we are in .NET world, makes your code coupled with the container, and this sounds like an antipattern since you use the container mainly for reduce code coupling.